# How can I make functions available to ClojureScript's eval?

Tags: eval, clojurescript

In [this blog post by Dmitri Sotnikov](http://yogthos.net/posts/2015-11-12-ClojureScript-Eval.html) a function `eval-str` is provided for running a string containing ClojureScript:

```clj
(defn eval-str [s]
  (eval (empty-state)
        (read-string s)
        {:eval       js-eval
         :source-map true
         :context    :expr}
        (fn [result] result)))
```

If I have some function `x` that I want to be able to call from inside the eval string, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer, assuming `x` is a var associated with a ClojureScript function:

1. The compiler analysis metadata for `x` needs to be present in the state passed as the first argument to `cljs.js/eval`. This is so that, during compilation, things like the arity of `x` is known, for example.
2. The JavaScript implementation of the function associated with `x` needs to be present in the JavaScript runtime. (This is especially true if the function is actually *called* during the `cljs.js/eval` call, and not just referenced.)

If `x` is a core function (say the var `#'cljs.core/map` for example), then both of these conditions is automatically satisfied. In particular, the metadata will be produced when `cljs.js/empty-state` is called (assuming [`:dump-core`](https://clojurescript.org/guides/self-hosting) is `true`), and the implementation of the core functions will have already been loaded into the JavaScript runtime.

But, let's say `x` is a wholly new function that you wish to have compiled in the self-hosted environment. The “trick” is to set up and reuse compiler state: For example put the result of `(cljs.js.empty-state)` into a var, and pass it to every `cljs.js/eval` call. If you do that, and one of the `cljs.js/eval` calls involves compiling a `defn` for `x`, then the compiler state will be *modified* (it is actually an atom), with the result being that the compiler metadata for `x` will be put in the state, along with, of course, the JavaScript implementation for `x` being set within the JavaScript environment (by virtue of evaluating the JavaScript produced for the `defn`).

If, on the other hand, `x` is a function that is part of your “ambient” ClojureScript environment (say, pre-compiled via the JVM ClojureScript compiler, but nevertheless available in the JavaScript runtime), then it will be up to you to somehow to arrange to get the compiler analysis metadata for `x` into the state passed to `cljs.js/eval`. If you look at the output of the JVM-based compiler, you will see `<ns-name>.cache.json` files containing such metadata. Take a look at the data that is in these files and you can ascertain its structure; with that you can see how to swap the needed information into the compiler state under `[:cljs.analyzer/namespaces <ns-name>]`. The `cljs.js/load-analysis-cache!` function exists as a helper for this use case, and a self-contained example is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51575204/4284484

Comment: This all seems incredibly complicated for what seems a fairly obvious usage requirement. Isn't there just a way to say "pass the namespace that calls the eval into the eval as its context"?

Comment: @interstar You'd want the namespaces _used_ by the string being evaluated to be available (which could differ from the namespace calling `cljs.js/eval`). While there could be a custom way to pass this to `cljs.js/eval`, another approach is to evaluate a `require` (or an `ns`) form prior to such code (or make direct use of `cljs.js/require`). In the event that required namespaces are already compiled, `cljs.js/*load-fn*` supports passing back compiled JavaScript along with the associated analysis cache.

Comment: @MikeFikes your suggestion to `'(require ...)` into the compiler state works great. Not sure if this will pass through :advanced compilation or not but will find out. Thank you!

Working code here for anyone who needs a relatively simple example:
https://github.com/chr15m/speccy/blob/957f7cbcb8b51cfb3d92616df15a1384d15d3517/src/speccy/core.cljs#L35-L47

(note the require on line 38).

Comment: @ChrisMcCormick Cool. By the way, self-hosted ClojureScript is only compatible with up to `:simple` optimizations.